# Passing Javascript variable to PHP link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a PHP link as follows, which appears inside a modal:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('Cart', ['controller' => 'payments', 'action' => 'cart', ]); ?>
```

I also have a script that brings up that modal:

```
$('.pay').click(function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    $('#payModal').modal('show');
    var bookingId = $(this).attr('data-id');
 });
```

I would like to try and get the JavaScript variable `bookingId` to be passed to the PHP link. I thought of doing it via a form, but I'm not submitting anything, so nothing would show up when doing a post/request.

Comment: Do you mean navigating to another page? You could do that with javascript: `window.location = '/yoursite.php?booking_id=' + bookingId`

Comment: The site I'm navigating to is in the format of `localhost\site\payments\cart\bookingId`. If I set `window.location` to that url, how does the user clicking the link actually take them to that location? And do I set `window.location` in a separate script, or in the same script that triggers the modal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the modal script, I added in the following:

```
$('.pay').click(function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var bookingId = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $('#payModal').modal('show'); 
    $('#payModal').attr('bookingId',bookingId); //added in this line, setting the bookingId variable as an attribute of the modal.
});
```

I then changed my PHP link to a standard HTML button:

```
<button onclick="cartredirect()">Proceed to Cart</button>
```

This then triggers a second JavaScript:

```
<script>
     function cartredirect(){
          var bookingId = $("#payModal").attr('bookingId'); //returns the modal attribute from before.
          window.location = "<?= $host . $basepath ?>/payments/cart/" + bookingId; //now as a result, the page with the correctly appended variable can load.
     };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I depends if you have other GET Parameters in your HTTP request. If there are none you can navigate to the current path and append your desired GET Parameter.

```
window.location = '?booking_id=' + bookingId; //navigate to the current page
window.location = './othersite.php?booking_id=' + bookingId; //navigate to another page
```

This will navigate to the *current* page with just the booking_id as GET parameter.

If you want to keep your other parameters you have to parse the current URL, append your paramteter, then serialize it back into an URL and change the location to it.

Just to clarify some things about relative links here:

```
//lets take the following URL as an example
'https://www.example.com/blog/pages/2984?id=3'

''       //current page --> 'https://www.example.com/blog/pages/2984'
'./'     //current 'directory' you are in --> 'https://www.example.com/blog/pages'
'../'    //parent 'directory' --> 'https://www.example.com/blog'
'../../' //2nd parent 'directory' --> 'https://www.example.com'
'/'      //root 'directory' --> 'https://www.example.com'
```

Comment: I'm trying to navigate from my current page to a new page though. I.e. User opens up the modal with the above script, then clicks on the link in the modal. That link in the modal then redirects the user to the new page, which is appended with the `bookingId` variable.

Comment: I managed to get it working in a different way but incorporating some of your answer with the `window.location`. I'll put my answer up shortly.

Answer (score -1):

**

> As You Already know PHP and Js Are Both Script languages and they bind
>   to a variable as they execute , so with the information you gave for
>   your js use

**

```
$('.pay').on ('click',function (ev) {
ev.preventDefault();
    $('#payModal').modal('show');
    var bookingId = $(this).attr('data-id');
 });
```

**if this doesn't work generate you link in js with append to html**